# How to make the post title available at my template

Tags: python, html, django

i need to know how i can make the actual postname a comment belongs to available at my template to display it later on:

views.py

```
def comment_edit(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    if request.user == comment.author:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=comment)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.author = request.user
                comment.published_date = timezone.now()
                comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm(instance=comment)
            return render(request, 'app/Post/post_comment_edit.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
```

template.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'post_list_by_category' pk=post.category.pk %}">{{ post.category.title }} </a>
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }} </a>
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: the only variable you're passing in the context to render the template is `form` (`{'form': form}`). So obviously in your template `post` is `None` and `post.pk` or `post.category.pk` are empty strings. You need to add a `post` variable to your context. Except it's not clear where that comes from, since your view is for a `comment`.

Comment: I also tought on that but how to pass them?

Comment: Just `{'form': form, 'post': comment.post}`.

Comment: Merci, that worked for me. I was just wondering where to set the post object at views.py. I didn't tought it would be that easy xD Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

pass the comment instance to your template

```
return render(request, 'app/Post/post_comment_edit.html', {'form': form, 'comment': comment})
```

and in template

```
<a href="{% url 'post_list_by_category' pk=comment.post.category.pk %}">{{ comment.post.category.title }} </a>
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=comment.post.pk %}">{{ comment.post.title }} </a>
```

Comment: Nope, this results in Reverse for 'post_list_by_category' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found
or
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found

i dont think that i really pass all arguments to the template

Comment: Updated the answer